# How to set state before render with react(redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to make a component able to redirect when not loggedIn.
Components were made with react, checking auth function works well with redux.

```js
//App.js
class App extends Component {
  checkUserInfo () => {
    const loggedInfo = storage.get('loggedInfo');
    if(!loggedInfo) return;
    const { UserActions } = this.props;
    UserActions.setLoggedInfo(loggedInfo)
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.checkUserInfo();
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.logged)
    return(...)
  }
}

export default connect((state) => ({logged: state.user.get('logged')}, (dispatch)=> ...)
```

and `UserActions.setLoggedInfo` action is look like this.

```js
...
export default handleActions({
  [SET_LOGGED_INFO]: (state, action) => {
    return state.set('logged', true)
  }
})
...
```

So, I want situation that component is redirected when auth is not logged in. I made a rendering component `<Route/>` with condition which is that `if state.logged==false`, `<Redirect to='login/>`.

But in very front point, logged is false before executing `checkUserInfo` function. so when I'm loggedIn, Redirect to `/login`, and when I'm not loggedIn, Redirect to `/login` too.

```js
//PrivateRoute.js
...
  render() {
     const { logged } = this.props;
     console.log(logged);
     return(
      <Route path="/myPage" render={props =>
        logged ? <Component/> : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login'}}/>
      }/>
    )
  }
...
```

this is screenshot what is `logged` value in console.

[image]

I want to skip very front state before set state by myFunction(`checkUserInfo`), how can I do.

plz help me.
and sorry to not good english syntax.

Comment: This is common issue. I would suggest your to read this article provided by react-router team - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow. It should help you.

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi I'll refer to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your global state before rendering the private component.

`render` prop provided by `Route` is a good place for that

```
<Route path='/secretarea' render={() =>{
    return props.isLoggedIn ? <SecretComp /> : <Login />
}}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set PrivateRoute like [this](https://medium.com/@tomlarge/private-routes-with-react-router-dom-28e9f40c7146)

This could help to check auth in simple way.